# PowerBI - How to mirror a report to another workspace

Tags: powerbi

Hey so I have a report in workspace `A` and I'm trying to mirror (reference) it to workspace `B` such that workspace `A` owns the report and can make changes to it, and for these changes to be updated in workspace `B`.

When I go on workspace `A` and use `save a copy` to save the reference to workspace `B` and then make a change to the report on workspace `A`, that change does not appear in workspace `B`.

I would really appreciate some help as I'm stuck on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't save a copy. Share the dataset with build permission.

[image: Build permission]

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-datasets-share